# Mouse behavior changes randomly (left button and scroll wheel)

Tags: mouse

I am running a wireless mouse on Ubuntu 21.04.   This issue started just under a week ago.  No previous issue before that.

Problem 1:
When I click left button on link it should just go to the page. Now sometimes it opens a new window. Once this happens, it will continue to do so until I go to terminal and type xev and move the mouse. Then it is good for a little bit but then the problem returns again.

Problem 2:
The scroll wheel will stop working. Now there is two fixes. One is with xev, the other is by simply pressing space bar on keyboard. Then it works for awhile again.

It is not the mouse because I have tested the mouse on my laptop and it works fine.  I have also tried another wireless mouse and have the same issue.  m

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 will be out of support very soon. Perhaps this is the time to make a fresh installation of 21.10?

Comment: Upgraded to 21.10 .. no change although from playing around I have notice that by changing the acceleration profile from adaptive to flat in system settings seems to reduce the problem popping up significantly.

Comment: A release upgrade is not the same as a fresh install and the latter was what I suggested (at least you should try a 21.10 live session for a while to assess if the problem persists). If there's something "weird" happening, perhaps the result of some previously installed software, such "weirdness" may be carried over to the upgraded release.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have way too much customization and a fresh install will result in too much work.  The fix I have is temporary and I have found more temporary fix.

Comment: Sure and I bet one of those customizations is the culprit here ;) Again, you can run a live session (no installation) to confirm.